# EJB lookup in Websphere from within the container

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I have a ejb module (EAR1) deployed in websphere and want to access this EJB from WAR which is also deplyed in the same Websphere.

I have tried with below code, which is not working.

```
public class RACAccessProvider {

    private InitialContext myInitialContext;

    public synchronized Object locateEJB(final Class clazz) throws ClassCastException, NamingException {

        try {
            System.out.println("looking up ejb.. for class " + clazz);
            Object obj;
            final String jndiName = clazz.getName();
            obj = myInitialContext.lookup(jndiName);
            System.out.println("###lookuop object.." + obj);
            return obj;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public RACAccessProvider() {
        System.out.println("Setting context in RACAccessProvider constructor...");
        final Properties context = new Properties();
        context.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");

        try {
            myInitialContext = new InitialContext(context);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code hangs at the line

```
obj = myInitialContext.lookup(jndiName);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You didnt write what WAS version are you using, but if you are on the same JVM just use `InitialContext ctx = new InitailContext();` without any props, second - if you are Java EE 6, you may try to use `@EJB` annotation instead of lookup.

Comment: Have you tried taking a thread dump during the hang to see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to check if your jndi name is correctly mentioned,
Also if initial context is initialized properly as per below code:

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
String snName = "java:comp/env/mail/your_jndiname";
Session session = (javax.mail.Session)ic.lookup(snName);
```